# Motivic integration of an Abelian variety and its dual are same?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, motives

Let $A$ be an abelian variety over $\mathbb{C}$ and $A^*$ the dual Abelian variety. The class of $A$ and the class of $A^*$ in $\mathcal{M}_{\mathbb{C}}=K_0(Var_\mathbb{C})[\mathcal{L}^{- 1}]$ are same?

In general, is there a pair of varieties (just finite type and separated, integral over $\mathbb{C}$) $(X,Y)$, such that these bounded derived categories are equivalence, but these motivic integrations are not same?

Comment: By Larsen-Lunts, if two varieties have the same class in $K_0(\operatorname{Var}_{\mathbb{C}})/(\mathbb{L}) )$ they are stably birational, which for abelian varieties means that they are isomorphic. Thus the answer is: if and only if $A$ and $A^*$ are isomorphic.

Comment: @abx But does this apply in the ring with $\mathbb L$ inverted, as discussed in the question?

Comment: @Will Sawin: The original question was in $K_0$ mod. $\Bbb{L}$, it was edited after my answer.

Comment: @abx It appears I fell victim to one of the classic blunders...

Comment: For abelian varieties, in particular, for A and A dual, derived equivalence does NOT imply equality in the Grothendieck ring localized at L. This is a result proved independently by Efimov and Ito-Miura-Okawa-Ueda by taking a homomorphism to the Grothendieck ring of Hodge structures. For simply connected varieties this is unknown and goes under the name of L-equivalence and D-equivalence conjecture. It is open, most importantly, for K3 surfaces.

Comment: @EvgenyShinder very interesting. Maybe you could post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Thank you abx and Will, and sorry for editing.

Comment: @EvgentShinder very interesting.  It seems weird that an isomorphism between motives (or equivalence of derived categories) $h(X)_{\mathbb{Q}} \simeq h(Y)_{\mathbb{Q}}$ in $Chow^\eff_{\mathbb{Q}}$ (or $D(X) \simeq D(Y)$)  doesn’t imply equality in Grothendieck ring $K_0(Var)[\mathbb{L}^{-1}]$. For smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C}$ $X$ and $Y$, if they are K-equivalent we hope they are D-equivalent (Kawamata conjecture), this implies $h(X) \simeq h(Y)$ (Orlov conjecture). On the other hand, K-equivalence implies equality of motivic integration....

Comment: Abelian variety and its dual is a counter example of D-equivalence $\Rightarrow$ K-equivalence, so it Make sense. But I wonder this phenomenons.